# Spring configuration class loading order with spring-boot @ConditionalOnMissingBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to enable custom configuration and sensible defaults using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`?
I have a spring boot application:

```
@Configuration
@Import({CustomConfiguration.class, DefaultConfiguration.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    ErrorListener errorListener;
}
```

and a `CustomConfiguration` that allows for either Spring xml or component scanning:

```
@Configuration("customConfiguration")
@ImportResource("classpath:customContext.xml")
@ComponentScan({"org.custom.impl"})
public class CustomConfiguration
```

The `DefaultConfiguration` uses `ConditionalOnMissingBean`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean 
ErrorListener errorListener() {
     return new LoggingErrorListener();
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is allow for a custom `ErrorListener` to be defined in the classpath, if not defined then use the default `LoggingErrorListener` (via the `ConditionalOnMissingBean`).  I'm finding that the `DefaultConfiguration` is always being used before the `CustomConfiguration`.

I've been experimenting with `@DependsOn` and `@Order` but no joy.

Comment: Conditional on what bean? The name? The type? You left out the matching part in the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

Comment: It defaults to the type of the `@Bean` it decorates.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` outside of an auto-configuration class if I were you, unless you can control the order of import of `@Configuration` classes. Auto-configuration does it explicitly, but normal user config classes (especially if they are `@ComponentSCanned`) do not have a defined order.

Comment: I have been experimenting with a `META-INF/spring.factories` and `@AutoConfigureBefore({ DefaultAutoConfiguration.class}`.  The DefaultAutoConfiguration still gets created before the CustomAutoConfiguration.  I think it's because my Application class has an autowired property which is somehow taking precedence over the `AutoConfigureBefore`.

Comment: That would be the way to go. And autowiring should have no bearing on condition evaluation (which has to happen before any beans are created). Can you update the question with your new code (or ask a new one)?

Comment: Dave, in my answer above, I've put my findings on it. Any loophole you see in that?

Answer (score -1):

In response to Daves answer: Looks like it works for independent beans which wouldn't interfere with Spring Boot. For example, when developing a library for Spring Boot applications, I wanted to provide a `RestTemplate` if one is not provided by the the application developer. `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` seemed to work:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RestTemplate.class)
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

To confirm whether it would work consistently, I gave a look at Spring's source code (e.g. see [ConditionEvaluator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConditionEvaluator.java)). Seemed that Spring skips creating beans with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations in the first pass. It would then do a second pass to configure these beans.

Also, I saw that `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` works well on `@Configuration` classes or `@Beans` inside configuration classes. But it does not work properly elsewhere, e.g. on or inside classes annotated with `@Component`.

Comment: That still makes an assumption about the order of registration of the configuration. Unless you use auto configuration it is hard to control. It might be that it works in tests as you wrote it, but it will fail if your conditional config is ever registered before the one with the intended override.