# Is there any way to create a @ConditionalOnMissingBean but only after spring is fully configured?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring Boot Starter for a college project on Java Reflection and Bytecode alteration.
The Reflection/Bytecode is done now, but it will scan for Spring `@Controller`s/`@RestController`s so it can detect certain annotations to run the process.
My question here is what's the best approach? Seems to me that an annotation processor doesn't quite work nicely, and my idea is to create a `@Configuration` class. Now I need to ensure that all `@Controller` beans have been booted before I actually process them and I also need to put the result of this processing in a bean that could already exist.
So for example:

```java
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired //I want to autowire but it may not exist, if the user doesn't define I need to create it
    private ExternalAnnotatedRequestsModel model;

    @Autowired // needed for the framework to acess spring controllers
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

    @Bean // this can also be overriden since the definitions can be done via yaml
    public ExternalRequestsProvider() {
         return new AnnotationExternalRequestsProvider(ctx);
    }

}
```

Now I also want that when the `ExternalRequestsProvider` bean is started, it runs the process method and saves the result in the object in the "model" variable.

Comment: Check this question for a better overview of how `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568728/spring-configuration-class-loading-order-with-spring-boot-conditionalonmissingb

Answer (score 0):

Using `@EventListener` for `ApplicationReadyEvent` to run your process after Spring is fully configured.

```java
@Configuration
public class ExternalRequestsConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ExternalAnnotatedRequestsModel model;

    @Autowired
    private ExternalRequestsProvider provider;
    
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReady(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // do your process
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that make the autowires not be null? Im gonna test it tho thanks

Comment: what is type of your `ExternalAnnotatedRequestsModel`? It must be a bean if you want to autowire it.

Comment: It is a bean. Imagine swagger like bean. When the user can define it and customize but there is a fallback bean in order for it never to be null

Comment: I don't fully understand the `swagger like bean` part. Can you please add the code for `ExternalAnnotatedRequestsModel` and `ExternalRequestsProvider`? Thanks.

Comment: I mean i could but there is no code yet. im trying to fix the wiring issue before actually running, right now they just hold a version string (model).

Comment: When i say swagger like is a bean that you (as an end user) can define but if you dont it gets defined for you. Much like Spring Boot Actuator where if you define no metrics if pre defines a group of them